# Get values of items inside a table

Tags: lua

```
local sometable = {a = "ag", b = "fa"}
for k, v in ipairs(sometable) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

The code above is my effort, so how do i print a, b in that table?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong iterator. `ipairs` is for sequences. For hash-like tables, use `pairs` instead:

```
for k, v in pairs(sometable) do
```

Answer (score 0):

`ipairs` only traversers the *array* part of a table. What you can do is simply writing

```
print(sometable.a, sometable.b)
```

or you can cycle through both the dictionary and array parts of the table by using

```
for key, value in pairs(sometable)
```

You could also define your own iterator to only cycle through the dictionary part of the table. In my mind it would look like

```
function cycle(dict)
    local contentarray = {}
    for k, v in pairs(dict) do
        contentarray[#contentarray + 1] = {k, v}
    end
    local n = 0
    return function()
        n = n + 1
        if not contentarray[n] then
            return
        else
            while type(contentarray[n][1]) ~= "string" do
                n = n + 1
            end
            return contentarray[n][1], contentarray[n][2]
         end
    end
end
```

But that would be higly inefficient.

Comment: `ipairs` only traverses the [_sequence_](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1) part of a table.